# Only download app from android market

Tags: android

I want to prevent android market to install downloaded android application automatically. Rather I want an app gets downloaded from the market and then a custom installer will responsible for its installation.

I am using android SDK 2.3

Anyone help is really appreciated.

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: I haven't tried anything because I m not getting a way to do it. I am just wondering if we could intercept between post-downloading and pre-installation phase. Another thought that market handovers installation procedure to the android package manager rather than installing itself. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

> I am just wondering if we could intercept between post-downloading and pre-installation phase.

No, sorry, that is not possible.

You are welcome to have the Market-installed application download and prompt the user to install a second application, but the first application still exists.

Comment: Does it mean that we cannot prevent market to install any download application?

Comment: @Sam: If you do not want an application to be installed from the Market, do not distribute it on the Market.

Comment: Here I am referring to all android applications that exists in market not mines. Actually I want to test any application that is being downloaded from market and then install it.

Comment: @Sam: That is not possible, because while you might "want to test any application that is being downloaded from market and then install it", others will want to replace "test" with "infect".